# What does the "f" flag refer to when installing Debian?

Tags: debian

I am in the process of setting up a Debian server and during the installation noticed the flag "f". What does this refer to?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume it means the partition is to be formatted.

Comment: Can there be any other flags and if so what would they be?

Comment: Evidently, that would be "formatted or 'set up a Linux swap area'".

Comment: The bootable flag seems to be denoted with a capital B.